# get the Field datas according to the Ids from the Collection in the Firestore/SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

so, the problem that need to be solved. we need to be able to get the data of any user(Field) in the "users"-(Collection) according to the its ID

[image]

these are my attempts:

FriendProViewModel() :

```swift
@Published var uid: String
@Published var displayName: String
@Published var email: String

init(uid: String, displayName: String, email: String) {
    self.uid = uid
    self.displayName = displayName
    self.email = email
}
```

And to check the result:

```swift
@State var data = [FriendProViewModel]()


let db = Firestore.firestore()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach((self.data), id: \.self.uid) { item in
            Text("\(item.displayName)")
            Text("\(item.email)")
        }
    }.onAppear {
//            self.fetchData()
        self.fetchData2()
    }
}

func fetchData() {
        // Remove previously data to prevent duplicate data
        self.data.removeAll()
        self.db.collectionGroup("users").getDocuments() {(querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let uid = document.documentID
                    let displayName = document.get("displayName") as! String
                    let email = document.get("email") as! String

                    self.data.append(FriendProViewModel(uid: uid, displayName: displayName, email: email))
                }
            }
        }
    }

func fetchData2() {
    
    db.collection("users").document("pJSsQQ2qt6Xx9qqRGpVzRfWLgC33").getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result I am getting for **fetchData()**:

[image]

Here is the result I am getting for **fetchData2()**:

[image]

**fetchData()** retrieves all data from all "users". **fetchData2()** is only getting data according to the *id* I gave.
separately, I was unable to get the data of each according to the *id*-s...

I hope everyone understood the question. thank you for your attention ...

Comment: I am not sure the question is clear;  `fetchData()` fetches data from all users. `fetchData2()` fetches data of one user - which is exactly what that code does.  It looks like you're storing each users document with the documentId being the users uid, that's pretty common practice so it's not clear what isn't working - `fetchData2` will retrieve any user by that uid (the documentId). Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: @Jay I quoted `fetchData()` and `fetchData2()` as telling my own attempts. The problem is that in this picture (https://i.postimg.cc/TP4fxg0J/Screen-Shot-2022-05-03-at-10-48-19.png), when I click on any user, has to display his **email** and **fullname**

Comment: The issue is still not clear to me. What's shown in that image is a users email and fullname, no? What does clicking it have to do with it already being shown? The console output in your question also shows the displayName and email. Your question states **we need to be able to get the data of any user(Field) in the "users"-(Collection) according to the its ID** and you have that data already, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting up and using `FriendProViewModel` correctly.
Read-up on how to use `ObservableObject`.

Re-structure your code to use a `ObservableObject` and its constituent structs, such as:

```
// a struct to hold each individual info
struct FriendModel {
    var uid: String
    var displayName: String
    var email: String
}

// an observable, to let the view know when it changes
class FriendProViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var friends: [FriendModel] = []
}
```

Declare it like this in your View:

```
 @StateObject var viewModel = FriendProViewModel() // instead of `data`
```

and use it like this:

```
 viewModel.friends.append(FriendModel(uid: uid, displayName: displayName, email: email))
```

and

```
 ForEach(viewModel.friends, id: \.uid) { item in ...}
```

I also suggest you move the `fetchData()` etc... inside the `FriendProViewModel`